# Таймер на js,проблема с функцией

Tags: javascript, html

Задача:Сделать условия для таймера,при которых,когда время (counter) < 60 секунд,показывалось не в формате Минуты:Секунды,а только Секунды.
Проблема: Когда счётчик доходит до 61,после этого резко становится 59,игнорируя число 60,в консоли видно,что до 61 и консоль и счётчик действуют одновременно,но,когда в консоли доходит до 60 сам счётчик показывает 59,соответственно далее они показывают числа с разницей в 1,в чём может быть проблема?
Заранее спасибо.

```js
var counter = 65; //время в сек.
function count() {
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = parseInt(counter / 60) + " мин. " +
    (counter % 60) + " сек.";
  console.log(counter);
  counter--; //уменьшение счетчика
  if (counter < 60) {
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = (counter % 60) + " сек.";
    if (counter < 0) {
      alert("Время на регистрацию истекло.");
      window.location = "log.html";
    }
  };
  setTimeout(count, 1000);
};

count();
```

```html
Осталось: <span id="count"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`counter--;` у Вас стоит в неправильном месте. Проследите логику при `counter` равном `60` на входе в функцию.

```js
var counter = 65; //время в сек.
function count() {
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML =
    parseInt(counter / 60) + " мин. " + (counter % 60) + " сек.";
  console.log(counter);
  if (counter < 60) {
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = (counter % 60) + " сек.";
    if (counter < 0) {
      alert("Время на регистрацию истекло.");
      window.location = "log.html";
    }
  };
  counter--; //уменьшение счетчика - вот где надо
  setTimeout(count, 1000);
};

count();
```

```html
Осталось: <span id="count"></span>
```